# before_remove to abort removal crashes server when throwing exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5's Association Callbacks. I read in the documentation that if you want to abort an object removal from an association you have to throw an exception:

> If a before_add callback throws an exception, the object does not get added to the collection. Similarly, if a before_remove callback throws an exception, the object does not get removed from the collection.

I'm doing exactly that but the server is crashing with a:

```
UncaughtThrowError (uncaught throw :abort)
```

This is how my code looks like:

```
def can_remove_association(object)
  return unless object.condition
  errors[:base] << "Can't be removed."
  throw(:abort)
end
```

Any clue what's going on? The `throw(:abort)` is avoiding the object to be removed, but I get an ugly 500!

Some reference: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/13/rails-5-does-not-halt-callback-chain-when-false-is-returned.html

Comment: are you sure that `throw` is correct? I have never seen that. I usually use `raise`

Comment: see https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-throw

Comment: Were you able to solve it using throw? I'm getting the same error. But i'm sure i've used it elsewhere and i'm clueless why isn't it working here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use

```
raise('abort')
```

See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-throw

and https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-raise

Comment: I just tested it and is not working , edited my question with more info.